# Ubuntu: How to add Systray notification icon using an ruby app?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, systray

I would like to create a ruby app which will install a notification icon in ubuntu systray (just like Skype, DropBox etc).

What would be the exact instructions to accomplish this? Pointers (or links) would be good too, to help me get started. I have no clue when it comes to ubuntu app programming.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer depends on what desktop you are using. For both gnome and unity, [libappindicator](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators) seems to work. Maybe [this](https://github.com/denysonique/ruby-libappindicator) will help you using it in ruby. You might need to [configure unity](http://www.howtogeek.com/68119/how-to-bring-app-icons-back-into-unitys-system-tray/) to allow your application to use the systray, though.